# Azure Virtual Machine Instance Level Public IP with Public IP Prefix

Tags: azure, azure-networking

The documentation of Azure is quite overwhelming, so I hope I can get an answer here. I've recently started playing around with Terraform and Azure, with success.

When creating a Public IP Prefix and assigning one of the IPs from the range to a Virtual Machine, it seems (also according to documentation) Azure creates a 1:1 NAT, so the IP address is not directly available on the NIC.

I did come across a piece of documentation mentioning Instance Level Public IPs, which showed (in the diagram) the IP being assigned directly to the VM.

So, is it possible to assign Public IPs from the Public IP Prefix pool directly to a VM as a secondary or primary network interface? The VM must have two NIC, one with a private address and one with a public address. If this is possible, how are security policies handled? I now use a Network Security Group and its rules, but I'm afraid I might lose this option.

I'm dealing with VMs which will be doing VoIP kinds of services like SIP and RTP. While these services do support being behind NAT, I'd like to have direct access to the public IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public IP's are never assigned directly inside the guest OS, you will always see this as a private IP. It is not supported to make changes to the IP configuration in the guest OS.

As you say, Instance Level IP's are an ASM service, which are getting retired soon, so I would not recommend you go down that route.

Comment: Thanks Sam for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the official Azure documentation, and other sources on this matter, I’m attempting to answer my own question:

1) ILPIPs are only available in ASM (or Classic).

2) ILPIPs are limited to 5 dynamic addresses, so they cannot come from a PIP Prefix pool.

3) ILPIPs bypass any network policy enforcers put in place by Azure, so firewalling must be done on VM level.

If any of this is not true, or perhaps outdated, please let me know.